# UIView not showing up the complete image

Tags: ios

UIView has spanned through the whole screen but the image I have set on it is not completely shown. rather the view takes a bit of image and displays that on the whole view. I have used the following statement to set the image

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:
    [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Base-Bg-1.png" ]]
];
```

Comment: Nobody can say if doesn't see what you are doing with constraints, but most likely, you have wrong constraints on the image or some property like clips to bounds or contentMode is not as it should. Check those

Comment: content mode is aspect fill and clip to bounds option is unchecked

Answer (score 0):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Base-Bg-1.png"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image]];
```

On writing this instead of the above posted statement my problem is solved.